# RNG generates 20 numbers/s between [9,10]. What's the probability it produces a $n\in[9.575,9.585]$ within 9.58 seconds

Tags: probability

RNG generates 20 numbers/s between [9,10]. What's the probability it produces a $n\in[9.575,9.585]$ within 9.58 seconds. Use that number to approximate the probability it fails at least 12 out of 100 times (Hint: Use normal RV)

So we're supposed to use exponential RV for this. So just double checking my work. $\lambda=.01*20*9.58=1.916$ and then x=1 so.

P(X=1)=$(1.916)*e^{-1.916}$, which is the probability it produces a number in that interval within 9.58 seconds.

The second part I'm not sure how to do.

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  Since each random selection is between $9$ and $10$, what's the point of setting the lower limit at $.585$?   Isn't that the same as $n\in [9,9.585]$?  Also, since about $192$ random selections are made in your $9.58$ seconds, the probability that you never see one between $9$ and $9.585$ is effectively $0$.

Comment: @lulu I apologize that was a typo

Comment: Ok, so the probability that a given random selection is out of the target range is $.99$...making the probability that all $192$ of the trials are out of the range $.99^{192}\approx .146$.  So the probability of att least one success is $1-.146=.854$  yes?  Now just use the normal approximation as suggested (though you could certainly do it with a straight binomial calculation).

Comment: So you want probability that it fails at least 12 out of 100. I also don't think that exponential variable is correct. Cause it should be the prob it produces a number in that range within 9.58 seconds not it produces 1 number in that range.